# How to count how many times a string appears in another string in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I used code below

```
set var=mystringstring
echo %var%|find /c "str"
```

and it returned `2` as expected.

However, when I try to store it in a variable like

```
set var=mystringstring
set var= echo %var%|find /c "str"
```

it returned `0`, and `var` remained `mystringstring`.

Comment: I think you need to look at - `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`.  The variable is then addressed as `!var!`.

Comment: This isn't BASH. To capture the output of a command in a Windows Batch File you use a FOR /F command.

Comment: @Squashman I know I can use FOR /F but It seems silly to use loops on a single result, which is the number of times of presence.

Comment: Your code example actually does not output two.  The `FIND` command only counts occurrences once per line.  Your code example only outputs one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the number of occurrences of string within another string you can do this.

```
@echo off
set var=mystringstring
set n=0
set x=%var%
set "x=%x:str=" & set /a n+=1 & set "x=%"
echo The string "str" occurs %n% time(s) in "%var%"
pause
```

Comment: Yes, this is obvious... **`;)`**  +1

Comment: @Aacini, **“Good artists copy, great artists steal”**

Comment: I don't really understand the line `set "x=%x:str=" & set /a n+=1 & set "x=%"`. Could you please tell me how it works(I guess it counts once per replacement).

Comment: @microwaver, the trick is the substitution with the `set` command. For every occurrence of the string  it is replacing it with another set command to iterate the number of occurrences.  The best way to visualize it is to actually see it.  Turn `ECHO ON` at the top of the script and watch it execute.  Once you see how the actual code is executing it will be very clear.